# Password Strength Meter - Error: SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to customize a password strength meter for a project but I keep getting a invalid quantifier error with the RegEx syntax in Javascript/jQuery. I've tried escaping backslashes, eliminating the forward slashes, searching on stack and Google. I have found some information regarding this but their solutions just don't seem to help me. I'm hoping that someone out there may be able to spot it in my function code below. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$('#rPassword').keyup(function() {
    return passwordChanged();
});

function passwordChanged()
{
    var pwd = $('#rPassword').val();
    var noofchar=/^.*(?=.{3,}).*$/;
    var checkspace=/\s/;    
    var best = /(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/; // 8 character minimum, upper-case letter, Lower-case letter, digit, special character
    var strong = /(?=^.{8,}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/; // 8 character minimum, upper-case letter, lower-case letter, digit or special character. Examples: “15NotEasy”,”Bett.er-Yet”
    var weak = /(?=^.{6,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$/; // 6 character minimum, upper-case letter or lower-case letter, digit. Examples: “common1″,”7etmein”
    var bad = /[a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]{3,}$/; // 3 characters or longer, digits, upper or lower case letters. Examples: “easy”,”8892″,”NOTSECURE”

    if (true==checkspace.test(pwd)) {
        $('#rPasswordStrength').animate({
            width: '0%',
            backgroundColor: '#eb001f'
        }, 500)
    } else if (false==noofchar.test(pwd)) {
        $('#rPasswordStrength').animate({
            width: '0%',
            backgroundColor: '#eb001f'
        }, 500);
    } else if(best.test(pwd)) {
    $('#rPasswordStrength').animate({
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#1ca456'
    }, 500);          
    } else if(strong.test(pwd)) {
        $('#rPasswordStrength').animate({
            width: '75%',
            backgroundColor: '#8eda2a'
        }, 500);              
    } else if(weak.test(pwd)==true && bad.test(pwd)==true) { 
        $('#rPasswordStrength').animate({
            width: '50%',
            backgroundColor: '#ff7e0b'
        }, 500);              
    } else if(bad.test(pwd)) {
        $('#rPasswordStrength').animate({
            width: '25%',
            backgroundColor: '#eb001f'
        }, 500);              
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point in writing `== true`

Comment: Those all work just fine for me in Firefox.

Comment: I wonder what's going on with mine then as I keep getting that error for some reason.

Comment: regarding the == true.. you are referring to weak.test(pwd) && bad.test(pwd) correct?

Comment: What's the point of `(?![.\n])`?

Comment: It doesn't give a line error in the error console. It just time stamps and says SyntaxError: invalid quantifier. I know it related to the code above as I don't get the error until it is called.

Comment: @Bergi beats me. It was in the code I copied from the example. I'm still trying to figure out RegEx's

Comment: @SLaks Responded above. Forgot to @ ya.

Comment: @RawAnimal: So you are getting an error when calling it? Then you will need to show us *how* you are calling it, and with which values (`console.log(pwd)`)

Comment: @Bergi Sure thing. Will add it to the code above

Comment: @Bergi I'm just calling the function on keyup when the user types into the rPassword field as indicated above. I'm not sure what you mean by console.log(pwd).

Comment: Which value did you type in so that it caused a syntax error?

Comment: @Bergi If I type any value into the input box it gives the error. I just did it by typing in a lower case a.

Comment: @Bergi I should add that the RegEx's seem to work. the function does properly update the output. I just get that error for some reason and I can't figure out why.

Comment: [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/FbwwN/). Please create a demo, tell us what browser you are using and post the exact error message. How do you know the error is related to this code at all?

Comment: @Bergi Will do. I felt that this is the code in question due to the error not occurring until I typed into the input which calls the function. I get the error in the error console each time I type and the event fires.

Comment: @RawAnimal: There might be other key event listener on that element…

Comment: @Bergi Everything is working great on the fiddle with the same browser that is giving me the error for my local code. Good point on the other event that could be on the element. I'll try to isolate and get back. Thanks for all of your help.